# How to detect internet connection types for WinRT App

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I used below code to detect internet connection type.

I tried the following conditions:

1. Disconnect Wifi for the laptop
2. Disconnect Cable internet connection for the Laptop

The problem:
with above 1 and 2 condition, the code still produced a result :
interface type 6  ("Internet connection (cable) ). How can this be?

I tried this and result the same:

1. Connect to Wifi
2. Disconnect the cable internet connection

What do I miss?

```
  private async void btnChkConnectionType_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

            var interfaceType = profile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType;

            // 71 is WiFi & 6 is Ethernet
            if (interfaceType == 71 )
            {

                txtBlkConnectionStatus.Text = "WiFi connection";

            }
            else if(interfaceType == 6)
            {

                txtBlkConnectionStatus.Text = "Internet connection (cable)";

            } //3G/Mobile Detect
            else if (interfaceType == 243 || interfaceType == 244)
            {

                txtBlkConnectionStatus.Text = "Mobile Connection";

            }
            else
            {

                txtBlkConnectionStatus.Text = "Not common connection type.";

            } 


        }
```